# allow user to create a draft post but not publish wordpress

Tags: posts, user-roles

Im currently using User Role editor to modify permission for the user role. I'd like to be able to restrict the role from publishing a post. They can save the draft but they should not be able to publish. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Not sure why you ask this, maybe I am wrong but that's just an option in User Role Editor. Select the role and add it to the role or just leave it inactive imho.

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_insert_post_data` filter. Then check the user role. If user have specific role set-up post status. ( I don't test below script)

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_handler', '99');

function filter_handler( $data ) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $userRole = $user->roles ? $user->roles[0] : false;

    if ( $userRole === 'author') {
        $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
    }

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: where should I place this code? and what is 99?

Comment: `functions.php`, 99 it's a priority `Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed.` more about add_filter and priority: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/#parameters

Comment: it doesnt work unfortunately. The user can still publish the post.

Comment: Okay, I did a mistake. Script was updated. Just change `author` role to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Give the user the `edit_posts` capability but *not* the `publish_posts` capability.